# 401 Unauthorized on a .net core web api deployed in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I created a .net core web api with the standard template, I pubblished it to Azure and when I try to call it via postman I get always a 401 error.

The startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
            
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "LuloWebApiCoreMac3", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "LuloWebApiCoreMac3 v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

And my controller:

```
 [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
```

My appsetttings.json

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "x.com.co",
    "TenantId": "x-c220-48a2-a73f-1177fa2c098e",
    "ClientId": "x-3737-48a5-a6c0-7e3bc4f9a5c9",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Scopes" : "userimpersonation"

  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Then in Azure AD, I created an APP Registration with the following details:

[image]
[image]
[image]

on the webbapp itself:
[image]

If I go to the browser and type: https://m/api/weatherforecast
The browser is redirected automatically to the login page and it logs in correctly and redirects back to the above url, however I get this error, which is weird because get actions should be able to work in the browser
[image]

I also tried to test with postman, in postman I created a collection, and inside the collection I have a pre-request script like this:

```
var client_id      = pm.environment.get("clientId");
var client_sercret = pm.environment.get("clientSecret");
var token_endpoint = pm.environment.get("authUrl");
var scope          = pm.environment.get("scope");

pm.sendRequest({
    url: token_endpoint,
    method: 'POST',
    header: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
      body: {
          mode: 'formdata',
          formdata: [
            {key: "grant_type"    , value: "client_credentials"}, 
            {key: "client_id"     , value: client_id},
            {key: "client_secret" , value: client_sercret},
            {key: "scope"         , value: scope}      
        ]
      }
},  function(err, response) {
  const jsonResponse = response.json();
  
  console.log(jsonResponse);

  pm.environment.set("bearerToken", jsonResponse.access_token);
  console.log(pm.environment.get("access_token"));

});
```

Then I try to call the web api like this:

[image]

The webb appi is configured as .NET 5(Preview)

[image]

Comment: try to add [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = 
    JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] on your WeatherForecastController instead of [Authorize]

Comment: azure AD will return a token and then you need to send this token in every request. get or post, action only work when you will send the token in request

Comment: I already tried your first comment and it doesnt work, still the same error. both on the browser and on postman.

Comment: How are sending the token in postman. Authentication token must be send as bearer token.

Comment: Usually we create 2 app registrations to call AAD protected API. One is for client side and the other is for API side. But you use the same one app registration for both sides. It doesn't matter. It may can work in this scene. But the key of this issue is that you put "userimpersonation" as the `scopes`. I notice that you are using "client_credentials" flow , which means the **application permission** (rather than delegated permission) will take effect. So if you want to use delegated permission `userimpersonation`, you should choose another auth flow (eg. auth code flow or ROPC flow).

Comment: But if you need to use "client_credentials" flow with application permissions, you just need to specify the `"Scopes" : "api://{client id of the API app registration}/.default"`. Then the access token will include the `Writer` application permission, which allows you to call the API.